# How to capture when a recurring payment is executed in shopify?

Tags: shopify, payment, recurring-billing

I need to know how to detect recurring payments in shopify, so that when a recurring payment happens, perform an action.

In what part of shopify can I detect it, in the code, database?

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

There are no recurring payments or subscriptions in Shopify at this time. External Apps are used to fake that, so you'd be looking at how they work, and interacting with them to determine recurring payments.

If you mean recurring charges for Apps you make, there is an API endpoint you call that will tell you everything you want to know with a GET. As per the docs, see here:

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/billing/recurringapplicationcharge

Comment: Thank you @David Lazar for the information. Best regards